# How to use mysql to express one line in multiple lines

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql table.

```
  a  | b  | c
1 a1 | b1 | c1
```

I would like to use a SQL query to create a table like the one below:

```
  time | sessionCnt
1 a    | a1
2 b    | b1
3 c    | c1
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
  'a1' AS a,
  'b1' AS b,
  'c1' AS c
FROM dual;
```

Comment: `a1` is the column name or the data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: @FrankerZ, your rollback from OP's revision 3 from yours (revision 2) should be cancelled. Tables should not be posted as images but as text. Also, this query formatting is weird and hard to read.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat Then feel free to do so.

Comment: a, b, and c are columns
a1, a2 and a2 are data.

Comment: Can you give me the mysql query by using the above dual table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 'a' as time, 'a1' as sessionCnt
union
select 'b', 'b1'
union
select 'c', 'c1';
```